# how do I use sort in maps?

Tags: c++

how do you sort in maps? 

I've tried sort (`myMap.begin()`, `myMap.end()`), but it doesn't work andIi've treid to find the answer on the internet but no site explains how to use sort for maps specifically. and bdw my map has integers and their alphabetical representations.

```
int main(){
map<int,string> m;
// add integers at the end of the map
m.insert(pair<int,string>(2,"Two"));
m.insert(pair<int,string>(3,"Three"));
m.insert(pair<int,string>(4,"Four"));
m.insert(pair<int,string>(7,"Seven"));
m.insert(pair<int,string>(5,"Five"));

cout<<"Finding minimum value from map"<<endl;

map<int,string>::const_iterator it3;
it3 = min_element(m.begin(),m.end());
cout<<"The minimum value in the vector is "<<it3->first<<","<<it3->second<<endl;
cout<<endl<<endl;


cout<<"Sorting array.."<<endl;
sort(m.begin(),m.end());

cout<<"Array after sorting.."<<endl;
cout << "The size of v is: " << m.size() << "\nThe capacity of v is: ";
cout<<m.max_size()    <<endl;
cout<<"The content of v is:";
for (it3 = m.begin(); it3 != m.end(); it3++){
    cout << it3->first << "," << it3->second << endl;
}
cout<<endl<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What type of maps are you using? By definition a standard map automatically sorts on it's keys unless you are using an unordered_map

Comment: `std::map` already sorts by key. What sort do you want ?

Comment: wait i'll comment the code

Comment: Also it doesn't make sense if you are using an ordinary map and try to sort it using the values if that is what you are trying to do, if you want to do something like that you should consider a non-associative container like vector

Comment: Basically you can't re-sort a map, it sorts on anything that changes the keys. If you want to use some kind of container for storing pairs and you want to sort on the right hand value then I suggest you use a vector, or swap the order of your map to map<string, int> and it will auto sort for you

Comment: Looking at your comments you seem to misunderstand what a map does as you cout `sorting array...`, a map is not an array, also it is unclear what your sorting criteria will be

Comment: You refer to one map as a "vector" and the other as an "array". A map is neither of those things, and a vector isn't an array. I think you may have skipped ahead a few chapters in your fine book.

Answer (score 5):

Maps are ordered by key; you can't change that.

If you want to sort by key, then you don't need to do anything. If you want to sort by value or some other criterion, then you'll need another data structure.

Answer (score 4):

[C++ maps](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) are typically implemented as height balanced binary search trees. But in general, whatever the data structure be, which is used to implement the map, the main idea behind a map is it is already ordered by the key. So explicitly sorting it by key makes no sense. If you want to sort by value, you can use other data structures like storing the reverse map, etc.

Comment: Other implementations are possible; the important point is that they are ordered.

Comment: Other implementations of maps are possible in general. But the site says that in C++ `Maps are typically implemented as binary search trees.`

Comment: 1. I understand cplusplus.com doesn't have the best reputation when accuract is concerned. 2. "Typically" is they key word there, and you're omitting it.

Comment: The height balanced search tree representation of a map guarantees worst case time of `O(logn)` for any operation. I don't think there aren't many more data structures which can do this.

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay: Indeed, there aren't many, but there are some (e.g. skip-lists), so saying they "are implemented" as trees is misleading. Adding the word "typically", and a brief explanation of *why* being a tree makes it unsortable, would make this a great answer.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Other implementations are possible, but it's hard to imagine one which meets both the complexity requirements (O(lg n)) and the sorted criteria.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I can imagine higher-order trees and skip-lists quite easily. But let's not drag this argument further off topic - the answer is fine now it's been improved.

Comment: So the downvoting starts again?

Answer (score 3):

Maps are already sorted by default, so you don't need to sort it yourself. By default if you iterate through a `std::map` you get the elements from lowest to highest since `std::map` is implemented like:

```
template<
    class Key,
    class T,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T> >
> class map;
```

with `std::less<key>` as default comparator for sorting, if you want to have it sorted in a different way, just declare it as

```
std::map<Key, Value, Comparator>
```

instead of

```
std::map<Key, Value>
```